# How to performance tune windows azure blob access

Tags: c#, performance, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using windows azure blob storage. My problem is that the blob access is taking long time. The code which i am using to access the blob is as follows :

```
        public void GetBlob()  // blob access
        {
            Container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName);

            Blob = Container.GetBlobReference(BlobName);
            try
            {
                Blob.FetchAttributes();
            }
            catch (StorageClientException)
            { Blob = null; } // blob not present
        }
```

Please suggest if there is any scope for improvement in the code for faster performance ?

Comment: what is the size of your blob? Is it a BlockBlob or a PageBlob?

Comment: the blob is a block blob and size is 700 kb while testing

Comment: Btw the web role used for testing is sized as `small` instance

Comment: The code is fine.  Something maybe potentially happening with your storage account (judging on previous question asked).  I'd suggest contacting support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine and shouldn't be slow.

Where is this code running ? 
if it's in a web/worker role, make sure it's running from the same data-center as the blob storage : west-europe, north-america, ...